# Is there any class WMI to show a message box?

Tags: c#, wmi, authorize.net-cim

I'm writing a WMI project with C#. I want to know Is there any class in WMI (like Win32_Process, Win32_ScheduledJob,...) that to be used to show a message box. I don't want to use .vbs files because I think WMI itself can do that.

Comment: Is your C# app a console app or a winforms app?

Comment: There's `MessageBox.Show()`. Why do you need to use WMI?

Answer (score 3):

The [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is for management and retrieve information about the system. To show a message box you  must use the methods exposed for the language which you use like the [`MessageBox::Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx).

Comment: But if your app doesn't run as this time, how can it show a message box. So my aim is want to register a task that will be done at specified time to wmi. The task can be automatically launch a program, shutdown computer or display a messagebox. And I succeed in registering a task to launch a program automatically (by using Win32_ScheduledJob class) and shutdown computer automatically (by using Win32_OperatingSystem class). Win32_ScheduledJob and Win32_OperatingSystem are classes in WIM. So I think it alse has a class that help raising a messagebox automatically (even if your app doesn't run.)