# How to show a messagebox after a specified time? (using WMI)

Tags: wmi, message, show, messagebox, msgbox

how to show a message box after a specified time?
i want to register a task into CIM. That task show a messagebox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any class WMI to show a message box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694277/is-there-any-class-wmi-to-show-a-message-box)

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing the wrong tool for the job, The [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not for display messages.

Comment: no.i think WMI can finish this request. Because the code VB can make it through WMI, but i don't want VB script. I want to use C#